# UIScrollView direction from scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to retrieve the direction that a `UIScrollView` is scrolling to, in the method;

> -(void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

If so, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
  xCoord = scrollview.contentOffset.x;
}

-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{

   if (xCoord > scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
     //RIGHT
   } else if (xCoord < scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
     //LEFT
   }

}
```

store the x coord of the scrollViews contentOffset when it begins scrolling, then compare it in scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating

Comment: Jamie's answer will not work in the case where paging is enabled and the user does a short flick and the UIScrollView bounces back to the original position. In that case, the contentOffset will sometimes look like this: 15, 20, 18, 15, 10, ...so the initial direction you calculate will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of paging try this

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    _xCoord = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if (_xCoord > scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
      //right
    } else if (_xCoord < scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        //LEFT

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the question, but might be useful for some – to retrieve the direction that a `UIScrollView` will decelerate:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  let point = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView)
  if point.x < 0 {
    // Will decelerate to the right
  }else if point.x > 0{
    // Will decelerate to the left
  }
}
```